# Binding is not happening on Object Property and text Input

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I am trying bind an Object property value to a text field. (Well I have taken this as an example ... I have no.of form fields and to be bound by other values)

But when change its value on button click the text field is not getting updated?

Below is the example code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application 
minHeight="600"
minWidth="955"
xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
<fx:Declarations>

</fx:Declarations>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        [Bindable]
        var currentFormItem:Object = new Object();

        public function changeName():void
        {
            currentFormItem.name = "hello";
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:HGroup>
    <s:TextInput id="test"
        text="{currentFormItem.name}"/>

    <s:Button click="changeName()"/>

</s:HGroup>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for this. I can just wrap this object in ObjectProxy.